# How do I change the extension of a C# DLL when compiling with Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working with a C# based "Scripting" API. To have the application recognize my script i need to have the extension of the DLL be (libname.esapi.dll). I could accomplish this by changing the AssemblyName Property of the project, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution that would keep my fully specified names a little shorter for reflection operations in the future.

Is there a proper post build commandline to do this?

Comment: Are you just adding "esapi" to the name? "dll" is still the extension in your example, so that didn't change. Could you just get away with a `rename`? Or change the name of the assembly itself so that part is included.

Comment: Setting the *Application* assembly name and/or the *Build* output using the *Project properties* (.csproj is a kind of makefile) isn't just the **most elegant way**, but it's the **recommended standard and proper pattern**. Any other mean like renaming the file with a file manager or any process is to avoid. You can of course use the namespaces you want within the source code.

Answer (score -1):

> libname.esapi.dll

That is not a extension change. That is a file named `libname.esapi` with the extension `.dll`. Windows/the file System was given the abiltiy to support multiple points per filename in the last Milennium. Only the stuff after the last dot is the extension.

Added to the "feature" that it will hide extensions of some file types (like .exe), this has caused no end of accidental virus installations.